# formal definition of lexical scope

Tags: programming-languages, variable-binding

I wonder if there is a formal definition of lexical scope so that people can prove things with respect to it, for example, that an interpreter implements lexical scope. You may ask what level of formality I am talking about. For example, I deem the usual definition of the free variables of a lambda term formal: a variable $x$ is free in a term $N$ iff

- $N$ is a variable $y$ and $x=y$, or
- $N$ is the application $M M'$ and $x$ is free in $M$ or $M'$, or
- $N$ is $\lambda y M$ and $x\neq y$ and $x$ is free in $M$.

Comment: It's basically the same definition. Or rather, the reverse: lexical scope is the region of the program in which the name is bound. You just need to desugar declarations into lambda abstractions, which will depend on the precise concrete syntax.

Comment: @rici Then “to implement lexical scope” means “to implement the region of the program”. :-(

Comment: I'd say "identify" rather than implement. The implementation, like the implementation of bound variables in the lambda calculus, involves the α-substitution with a unique name of bound variables. (For `let` -like constructions like declarations with initializers, you also need β-reduction.)

Comment: @rici Sorry, I do not think what you are saying is clear enough.